# Laravel ID obfuscating (Meaningless Numbers to Meaningful Title)

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a Laravel jenssengers MongoDB and it is my first time seeing the word obfuscating. I see many open source options on github but nothing that does what i want.

How do i obfuscate my url from looking like this

> http://blog.dev:8000/article/57780ee99a892008f64d5341

To looking like

> http://blog.dev:8000/article/how-to-do-this-article

My routes expect an article id like so

```
Route::get('/article/{article_id}', [
   'uses' => 'MainController@singleArticle',
   'as'  => 'article'
]);
...And Controller
public function singleArticle($article_id){
    $article = Article::find($article_id);
    return view('article',['article' => $article]);
}
```

And i am assuming it is quicker working with ids rather than text.(Correct me if i am wrong) Therefore changing the route to ...

```
Route::get('/article/{article_title}', [
   'uses' => 'MainController@singleArticle',
   'as'  => 'article'
]);
```

and controller to

```
public function singleArticle($article_title){
    $article = Article::where('title',$article_title)->first();
    return view('article',['article' => $article]);
}
```

Would be a bad choice that i might regret later when two articles have the same title?

So how do i obfuscate my routes, to look like the title of the article which is being fetched from the database?

Comment: Obfuscation is a different thing. What you want are url slugs, if i'm not mistaken. Have a look at these libraries for Laravel/Eloquent. https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable, https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

Comment: @Doom5 Thanks, exactly what i need. I knew that big word wouldn't help me solve anything. I will now stop learning how spell it.

Comment: +1 [https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable). I use it in several projects, and it just works.